# android-make whatsapp call

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I want to make a WhatsApp call to a specific user. I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("callto:" + phoneNUmber);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(i);
```

I know how to create a WhatsApp message, the code is similar and it works:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNUmber);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with relevant error logs/debug information.

Comment: Did you add the relevant `permissions` to the `manifest` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simple solution is, Query ContactContract.Data for the _id and MIME type.

```
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();  
cursor = resolver.query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

//Now read data from cursor like 

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
      long _id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
      String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
      String mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE));

      Log.d("Data", _id+ " "+ displayName + " " + mimeType );

}
```

The output will be like the following

> 12561 Snow  vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.profile
>
> 12562 Snow  vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call

Now save in DB or somewhere else only those _Ids whose MIME type is `vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call`

And then you initiate Whatsapp call with those contacts like this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

// the _ids you save goes here at the end of /data/12562     
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/_id"),
    "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call");
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: My two cents, please check the MIME type for smooth functioning.

Comment: how to do whatsApp video call like viop call using intent.?

Comment: what if I dont have the number in my contacts?

Comment: Is it possible to make whatsapp call without saving contact?

Comment: it is causing an error requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE  but i set the permission in manifest but error still occur <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>

Comment: @adnan-khan This solution does not work for me. Even no exception/error happens. It seems that the Intent is ignored.

Comment: yeah, @Coeus was right. This solution may work if we Saved first the number in our contact after that we could do a whatsapp call. Means that the code is working because the target user whatsapp is already in our contact.

Comment: 2021 This works fine! Just remember you need the DataID, not the ContactId or RawContactId.

Answer (score 13):

To make WhatsApp video call use below mime-string:

```
String mimeString = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.video.call";
```

To make WhatsApp voice call use below mime-string:

```
 String mimeString = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call";
```

Use Below Code:

```
 String displayName = null;
 String name="ABC" // here you can give static name.
 Long _id;
 ContentResolver resolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
 cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    _id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
    displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE));
    if (displayName.equals(name)) {
        if (mimeType.equals(mimeString)) {
            String data = "content://com.android.contacts/data/" + _id;
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            sendIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(data), mimeString);
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me. Even no exception/error happens. It seems that the Intent is ignored.

Comment: @Fartab same as you, have you found solution yet?

Comment: @hemaezzat It was three years ago but I think didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 6):

this code is to check number has whatsapp or not   and  make whatsapp audio and video call

first  check wether  number have whatsapp   or  not  ...if you dont know

```
 if  rowContactId (return type of hasWhatsapp) is  not equal to '0'   then this number has whatsapp.
```

.

```
public String hasWhatsapp(  getContactIDFromNumber(795486179).toString(),MAinactivity.this ) 
{
        String rowContactId = null;
        boolean hasWhatsApp;

        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID};
        String selection = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND account_type IN (?)";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{contactID, "com.whatsapp"};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            hasWhatsApp = cursor.moveToNext();
            if (hasWhatsApp) {
                rowContactId = cursor.getString(0);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return rowContactId;
    }


public static int getContactIDFromNumber( contactNumber,Context context)
    {
        contactNumber = Uri.encode(contactNumber);
        int phoneContactID = new Random().nextInt();
        Cursor contactLookupCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,contactNumber),new String[] {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
        while(contactLookupCursor.moveToNext())
        {
            phoneContactID = contactLookupCursor.getInt(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
        }
        contactLookupCursor.close();        

        return phoneContactID;
    }


//your number is support for whatsapp then come to here  to make whatsapp  call
// this is for whatsapp call
 wtsapp_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String mimeString = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call";


                         Intent intent = new Intent();
                         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                //here you have to pass whatsApp contact  number  as  contact_number ..

               String name= getContactName( contact_number, MainActivity.this);
                int whatsappcall=getContactIdForWhatsAppCall(name,MainActivity.this);
                if (whatsappcall!=0) {
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/" +whatsappcall),
                            "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call");
                    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

                    startActivityForResult(intent, WHATSAPP_NUMMBER);
                }
            }
        });


//for whatsapp  video call
        wtsapp_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                       //here you have to pass whatsApp contact  number  as  number..

                        String name= getContactName( number, MainActivity.this);
                int videocall=getContactIdForWhatsAppVideoCall(name,MainActivity.this);
                if (videocall!=0)
                {
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/" +videocall),
                            "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.video.call");
                    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });

 public String getContactName(final String phoneNumber, Context context)
    {
        Uri uri=Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};

        String contactName="";
        Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contactName=cursor.getString(0);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        return contactName;
    }


 public  int getContactIdForWhatsAppCall(String name,Context context)
    {

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Data._ID},
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + "=? and "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+ "=?",
                new String[] {name,"vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call"},
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

        if (cursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            cursor.moveToNext();
            int phoneContactID=  cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
            System.out.println("9999999999999999          name  "+name+"      id    "+phoneContactID);
            return phoneContactID;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("8888888888888888888          ");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public  int getContactIdForWhatsAppVideoCall(String name,Context context)
    {
      Cursor  cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Data._ID},
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + "=? and "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+ "=?",
                new String[] {name,"vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.video.call"},
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

        if (cursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int phoneContactID=  cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
            return phoneContactID;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("8888888888888888888          ");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check your formatting next time. Your post had very low quality and suffered from indentation issues.

Answer (score 2):

If  we pass rawContactId, then we can use that to directly fetch the ID associated with the whatsapp call URI.

```
private void whatsAppCall(Context context, String rawContactId) {
        try {

            int id = whatsAppCallId(context, rawContactId);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String uriString = "content://com.android.contacts/data/" + id;
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uriString), "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call");
            intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "whatsAppCall Exception: " + e);
        }
    }



 private long whatsAppCallId(Context context, String rawContactId){ 
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

            String selection = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? ";
            String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call", rawContactId };


            Cursor cursor = resolver.query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, selection, selectionArgs,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            long _id=0;

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                _id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
                String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE));
                Log.d(TAG, "Data: " + _id+ " "+ displayName + " " + mimeType );
            }
return _id;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer provided by @Adnan Khan works in Android 11, but I wanted to provide the Kotlin version of his answer:

```
val resolver: ContentResolver = requireContext().contentResolver
val cursor: Cursor? = resolver.query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        null, null, null,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)

while(cursor!!.moveToNext()) {
    val _id: Long = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID))
    val displayName: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME))
    val mimeType: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE))

    Log.i("Intents", "$_id $displayName $mimeType")
```

Now, the intent in Kotlin goes like this:
_id is the value you get from the previous routing

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/_id"),
    "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call")
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
startActivity(intent)
```

Last but not least add the following to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
    androd:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
    androd:maxSdkVersion="30" />
```

After this, you need to go to Settings -> Apps -> Select your app and mark the two permissions as allowed.

There should be a way that the app ask you the first time it is run, but that is another topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
// first  check wether  number have whatsapp   or  not  ...if you dont know

  //if  rowContactId (return type of hasWhatsapp) is  not equal to '0'   then this number has whatsapp..

public String hasWhatsapp(  getContactIDFromNumber(795486179).toString(),MAinactivity.this ) 
{
        String rowContactId = null;
        boolean hasWhatsApp;

        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID};
        String selection = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND account_type IN (?)";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{contactID, "com.whatsapp"};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            hasWhatsApp = cursor.moveToNext();
            if (hasWhatsApp) {
                rowContactId = cursor.getString(0);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return rowContactId;
    }


public static int getContactIDFromNumber( contactNumber,Context context)
    {
        contactNumber = Uri.encode(contactNumber);
        int phoneContactID = new Random().nextInt();
        Cursor contactLookupCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,contactNumber),new String[] {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
        while(contactLookupCursor.moveToNext())
        {
            phoneContactID = contactLookupCursor.getInt(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
        }
        contactLookupCursor.close();        

        return phoneContactID;
    }


//your number is support for whatsapp then come to here  to make whatsapp  call
// this is for whatsapp call
 wtsapp_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String mimeString = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call";


                         Intent intent = new Intent();
                         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                //here you have to pass whatsApp contact  number  as  contact_number ..

               String name= getContactName( contact_number, MainActivity.this);
                int whatsappcall=getContactIdForWhatsAppCall(name,MainActivity.this);
                if (whatsappcall!=0) {
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/" +whatsappcall),
                            "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call");
                    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

                    startActivityForResult(intent, WHATSAPP_NUMMBER);
                }
            }
        });


//for whatsapp  video call
        wtsapp_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                       //here you have to pass whatsApp contact  number  as  number..

                        String name= getContactName( number, MainActivity.this);
                int videocall=getContactIdForWhatsAppVideoCall(name,MainActivity.this);
                if (videocall!=0)
                {
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/" +videocall),
                            "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.video.call");
                    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });

 public String getContactName(final String phoneNumber, Context context)
    {
        Uri uri=Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};

        String contactName="";
        Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contactName=cursor.getString(0);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        return contactName;
    }


 public  int getContactIdForWhatsAppCall(String name,Context context)
    {

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Data._ID},
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + "=? and "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+ "=?",
                new String[] {name,"vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call"},
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

        if (cursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            cursor.moveToNext();
            int phoneContactID=  cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
            System.out.println("9999999999999999          name  "+name+"      id    "+phoneContactID);
            return phoneContactID;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("8888888888888888888          ");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public  int getContactIdForWhatsAppVideoCall(String name,Context context)
    {
      Cursor  cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Data._ID},
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + "=? and "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+ "=?",
                new String[] {name,"vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.video.call"},
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

        if (cursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int phoneContactID=  cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
            return phoneContactID;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("8888888888888888888          ");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: guys follow this code    to  "check  number has whatsApp" ,for" WhatsApp Call"  and  "WhatsApp video call"     try  this  100% you will get exact result

Comment: dude this is too complicated can you make a video for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    iv_whatsapp_call.setOnClickListener {
        // val dialIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
        // dialIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:" + et_whatsapp.text.toString())
        // startActivity(dialIntent)
        val mimeString = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call"

        val resolver: ContentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
        val cursor: Cursor? = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)

        while(cursor!!.moveToNext()) {
            var Col_Index = cursor!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID)
            val _id = cursor.getLong(Col_Index)

            Col_Index = cursor!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
            var number = cursor.getString(Col_Index)

            Col_Index = cursor!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val displayName = cursor.getString(Col_Index)

            Col_Index = cursor!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.MIMETYPE)
            val mimeType = cursor.getString(Col_Index)
            // println("Data: " + _id.toString() + " ---" + displayName + "---" + number + "---" + mimeType )

            var my_number = et_whatsapp.text.toString()
            my_number = my_number.replace(" ","")
            my_number = my_number.replace("+","")


            if(number.isNullOrBlank() == false) {
                // println("Number : " + number )
                number = number.replace(" ", "")
                number = number.replace("+", "")

                // my_number.substring(1)
                // println(">>" + my_number)
                if (number.endsWith(my_number.substring(1) + "@s.whatsapp.net")){
                    if (mimeType.equals(mimeString)) {
                        val data = "content://com.android.contacts/data/$_id"
                        val sendIntent = Intent()
                        sendIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                        sendIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(data), mimeString)
                        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
                        startActivity(sendIntent)
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).