# How can I place a WhatsApp call from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, call, whatsapp

I would like to be able to place a call using a WhatsApp number from my iOS app. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think its possible to make a voice call via whatsapp from your own application. Here is WhatsApp documentation on what you can do: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: mm. I tried a lot and gave up finally. :(

Comment: It is posible in andoid .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655458/android-make-whatsapp-call. please let me know anyone has the update for the same ..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should ask WhatsApp how to do so.
The solution lies in URL Schema: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/de/iphone/23559013

Here the code copied from their site, in Objective-C. I'll keep it as an exercise to do so in Swift:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

And just to make it sure: They won't let you send messages *directly* to someone, and even more: They won't let you send you messages *silently*, without WhatsApp being opened before.

Comment: I tried this earlier. But my target was making call and found that is impossible.