# How to include whastapp app in the intent action_call

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my function

```
fun getActionIntent(uri : String?) {
        val phoneIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        phoneIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$uri")
        phoneIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
        ctxt.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(phoneIntent, "Send Sms"))

    }
```

I just get Phoneand Skype app in my chooser.
I want whatsapp to be add to the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Intent to call Whatsapp from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521937/android-intent-to-call-whatsapp-from-code)

Comment: It is not exactly what I want. When I use createChooser I get others apllications.I need to add whatsapp apllication to that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void openWhatsApp(String contactNo) {
    String smsNumber = contactNo; //without '+'
    try {
        String mess="your message";
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");

        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mess);
        sendIntent.putExtra("jid", smsNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        appCompatActivity.startActivityForResult(sendIntent,1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(appCompatActivity, "Error/n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Note: It directly open your whatsapp

Comment: This code works but is there a possibity to add whatsapp in ACTION_DIAL instead of ACTION_SEND

Comment: No there is no possibility

Comment: Thanks @eagerprince