# Android disconnect whatsapp video call programatically

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I have initiated a `WhatsApp` video call from my Android app as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51070920/3169868).

```
String contactNumber = "Your Contact Number"; // to change with real value

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver ()
.query (
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
    new String [] { ContactsContract.Data._ID },
    ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = 'com.whatsapp' " +
        "AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.video.call' " +
        "AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE '%" + contactNumber + "%'",
    null,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
);

if (cursor == null) {
// throw an exception
}

long id = -1;
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
id = cursor.getLong (cursor.getColumnIndex (ContactsContract.Data._ID));
}

if (!cursor.isClosed ()) {
cursor.close ();
}


Intent intent = new Intent ();
intent.setAction (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType (Uri.parse ("content://com.android.contacts/data/" + id), "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call");
intent.setPackage ("com.whatsapp");

startActivity (intent);
```

This opens `WhatsApp` and the video call starts. Now the user returns to my app to continue the workflow, while the video call continues as an overlay on the screen. After a while I want that the user should be able to disconnect the WhatsApp call from my app.

Can I also disconnect the video call from my app programatically? Otherwise the call keeps running in the background.

Comment: Only if there is an Uri scheme registered for that in whats App . Which i am afraid will not be there (IMO) .. Because i seems no sense to me to provide such Scheme .. If User is On call he/she can disconnect whenever they want .. Automatic disconnection is not good for UX .

Comment: The use case involves making a WhatsApp call from the app and completing the workflow in the app during which the WhatsApp call shows as a screen overlay. Now instead of disconnecting the call if the user closes the overlay the call continues in WhatsApp. Is there any solution to handle this?